# Suppose that $x <y$ Find the number $n$ such that $ \frac{x}{n} < \frac{y}{n+1}$

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $0<x < y$ Find the number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \frac{x}{n} < \frac{y}{n+1}$, for every $x, y$. Indeed I want to find two number $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b;$ such that for every $x < y,( x, y \in \mathbb{R})$ we have $ \frac{x}{a} \le \frac{y}{b}.  $ It's an idea of ​​mine to see if such numbers can be found to use for the open problem I've already stated here. This seems impossible because there is always a number between any two real number.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously false if $x=y$. However, it is true for $0<x<y$.

Indeed, let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{x}{n}<\dfrac{y}{n+1}$. Basic manipulations show that $n>\dfrac{x}{y-x}$. For example, you can take $n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{y-x} \right\rfloor+1.$

Comment: Thanks. But I want to get $a, b$ so that it is constant and doesn't really depend on any $x, y$,for every $x, y$.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that it depends on which way around your statement is meant to be considered.

If you want to prove:

- For all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < x < y$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{x}{n} < \frac{y}{n+1}$

then this is true - we can rearrange the inequality to get $\frac{n+1}{n} < \frac{y}{x}$ which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{y}{x} - 1$, and so $n > \frac{x}{y - x}$, and any $n$ that satisfies that inequality will work.

However, if you want to prove:

- There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < x < y$, $\frac{x}{n} < \frac{y}{n+1}$

then you're out of luck. Again, rearranging the inequality, we see that $\frac{y}{x} > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, so for any fixed value of $n$ we can also fix $x$ and then choose $y \in (x, x(1 + \frac{1}{n}))$ and the inequality breaks.

So in other words, if you want to satisfy the inequality by choosing a value of $n$ specific to a given $x, y$ pair, then you can. If you want to choose a value of $n$ that works for *every* $x, y$ pair, you can't.